# Retrieve multi-level data in a single query - MySQL Group Concat

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multi-level data in a single table as seen below.

- The category/brand is identified by having null parent id.
- The Product is identified by having parent id corresponding to top level
  category (mid).
- Each product can also have a subtype or variety of the basic version - this is identified by having a sub column corresponding to the mid of the basic product.

| mid | parent | sub | org | item | price | dsc1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  | 1 | Apple |  |  |
| 2 | 1 |  | 1 | iPhone | $1000 | (Description) |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 | iPhone Plus | $1200 | (Description) |
| 4 | 1 |  | 1 | iMac Basic | $600 | (Description) |
| 5 | 1 | 4 | 1 | iMac 1TB | $900 | (Description) |

The desired output is on the basic product level (not null parent + null sub) and it has to encompass a top level category as well as all sub varieties and descriptions:

```
Apple $1000 iPhone $1200 iPhone Plus (Description)
Apple $600 iMac Basic $900 iMac 1TB (Description)
```

I am trying everything possible with SQL but I cannot manage to combine everything in a single query - I don't want to first check for the category and then do another query for the individual products.

```
SELECT *, IF(parent IS NULL, item, mid) AS topcategory FROM table where org = "1";
```

I was also trying with GROUP_CONCAT without any luck:
https://phpize.online/?phpses=5c149faca3e15d3bcd7f4c0e437c28ff&sqlses=c40160db7e24f450d3055397db86aeda&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Answer (score 0):

I mean you can use next query:

```
SELECT 
    `parent`.`item` `parent`,
    `sub`.`item` `sub`,
    `sub`.`price` `sub_price`,
    `menu`.`item` `menu`,
    `menu`.`price` `menu_price`,
    `menu`.`dsc1`
FROM `menu`
JOIN `menu` `sub` on `sub`.`mid` = `menu`.`sub`
JOIN `menu` `parent` on `parent`.`mid` = `menu`.`org`;
```

[MySQL fiddle](https://phpize.online/?phpses=5c149faca3e15d3bcd7f4c0e437c28ff&sqlses=e6dcc28c01a8649a8a6c8f1dbe00ba9e&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

**Result**

```
+========+=========+===========+=============+============+======+
| parent | sub     | sub_price | menu        | menu_price | dsc1 |
+========+=========+===========+=============+============+======+
| Apple  | iPhone  | $1000     | iPhone Plus | $1221      | (HI) |
+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------+------+
| Apple  | iPhone  | $1000     | iPhone Red  | $1600      | (HI) |
+--------+---------+-----------+-------------+------------+------+
```